# Using box API without registering application with admin

Tags: box-api, box, boxapiv2

My company uses Box internally for managing a variety of documents. I created a script that reads a boxnote (which I am an editor of, and other users edit) periodically and emails me certain properties about that boxnote (i.e. it downloads the boxnote and parses the contents).

My script was using the developer token, which is only good for 30 minutes at a time. Is it possible to create a longer-lived token?

I tried:

1. "Custom App" with "OAuth 2.0 with JWT". Once I created the public/private keys, Box asked me to register the app with the administrator to use.
2. "Custom App" with "App Token". Again, once I clicked to generate the primary key, Box asked me to register the app with the admin.

Is there any way to do this without asking the Box admin for my whole company whether I can register an app which is basically 20 lines of Python code?

Comment: got a solution for this?

Comment: not yet, hopefully someone will answer...

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the answer to your question is a **No**.

You ***have*** to get the authorization for the app from the box admin if you are using *Server Side Authentication*.

However, you don't need authorization from admin if it is *User Authentication* but that makes the whole process tedious on the user.

Hope that was helpful.